# entity framework DDD

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I work on a EF Core project for WPF app.
We decide to split the DbContext in 2 smaller Dbcontexts: (the project contains a single Database)

```
public class FirstDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }  
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DBSet<Parameters>{ get; set; }            
}

public class SecondDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DBSet<User>{ get; set; }
    public DBSet<Books> { get; set; }
    public DBSet<Parameters>{ get; set; }  
}
```

and we keep a "super" DbContext (which contains all the DbSets from the DB) to maintain and migrate the DB

```
public class SuperDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }  
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DBSet<User>{ get; set; }
    public DBSet<Books> { get; set; }
    public DBSet<Parameters>{ get; set; }  
}....
```

The first step to refactor code is to replace the lines which references the "SuperDbContext..."  with the correct call "SecondDbContext.Books..."or "FirstDbContext.Post"... OK

Question:
In the Client app, the choice of DbContext is depending about a user's choice when app is launching: if user choose option1 => FirstDbContext, and if option2 => SecondDbContext.

How can we write the code to switch on the current DbContext to manage the "common DbSet" (Parameters) : before refactoring we have for example:
SuperDbContext.Parameters.FirstOrDefault()...
and now? do we have to write something like this:

```
if(option1)
{
    FirstDbContext.Parameters.First()
}else
{
    SecondDbContext.Parameters.First() 
}
```

And what is the impact in the repositories? cause if we maintain this approach we have to duplicate code in the 2 Repositories?

Answer (score 0):

No no... Forget about the approach you mentioned, you'll end up writing twice the code you need. Why don't you just use db context type :

At the beginning of your function, a single `if else` :

```
DbContext context;

if(option1)
{
    context = new firstContextEntities();
}
else
{
    context = new secondContextEntities();
}
```

And as both of your contexts are almost exactly the same, you will use your context by casting it to the greater one (the one that has the most access) :

```
var FirstLine = ((secondContextEntities)context).Parameters.First();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks but my question is on the "Shared" entities (or common data like Parameters table : how to manage all the common entities ? (is it the good solution to maintain every shared DbSet from each bounded context or create another one with only shared data ?). If i plan to maintain the common DbSets into each bounded contexts, i have to duplicate code into repositories ?

Comment: Wait, you have only one parameter table but two repository that use it ?

Comment: You need a complete logic architecture... StackOverflow is not going to provide you the whole théorie behind it.